# How to solve update part error in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel-4.2

I'm attending to *editprofile* details. **Update** Method in `Registercontroller.php`

```
public function updateprofile(){
   $id=Input::get('id');

    //validation part;
    $users= Register::find($id);
    $users->name=Input::get('username');
    $users->age=Input::get('age');
    $users->email=Input::get('email');
    $users->save();     
}
```

Form action attribute in `editprofile.blade.php`

```
<form action="updateprofile" method="post">
```

After change in some fields and update I got an error

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException13.
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
…\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php210
```

Comment: <form>is <form action="updateprofile" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" class="form-control"  name="id" id="id" value="{{$registers->id}}">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="{{$registers->email}}">

Comment: Regisert is my Model

Comment: show your route

Comment: Register or Regisert  which one ?

Comment: oh..sorry Register.php file in model.

Comment: Route::get('/editprofile/{id}','RegisterController@editprofile');
Route::post('/updateprofile','RegisterController@updateprofile');

Comment: put slash in your action"/updateprofile"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142952/discussion-between-jyothi-and-alexyui).

Comment: after update where your redirecting ?

Comment: $users= Register::find($id);
   $users->name=Input::get('username');
   $users->age=Input::get('age');
   $users->email=Input::get('email');
   if($users->save())
   {
    return Redirect::to('profile')->with('success','Successfuly updated');
   }
   else{
     return Redirect::to('editprofile')->with('fail','An error occured,please try again');
   }

Comment: how to solve Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException. error

Comment: when error showing what is your url right now ?

Comment: Route::get('/editprofile/{id}','RegisterController@editprofile');public function editprofile($id) is working

Comment: but Route::post('/updateprofile','RegisterController@updateprofile');
 public function updateprofile() is not working.